# Undo SBS 2011 Exchange power shell command

Tags: exchange

I am wanting to run this Exchange power shell command but before I do I want to make sure there is a command to reverse it if it doesn't work. Here is the command:

```c
Get-ReceiveConnector “My Internet ReceiveConnector” | Get-ADPermission -user “NT AUTHORITY\Anonymous Logon” | where {$_.ExtendedRights -like “ms-exch-smtp-accept-authoritative-domain-sender”} | Remove-ADPermission
```

Answer (score 2):

The only part of that command that makes any changes is `Remove-ADPermission`. And if you run everything else, you'll get enough information to be able to re-create the permissions you are removing:

> Get-ReceiveConnector “My Internet ReceiveConnector” | Get-ADPermission -user “NT AUTHORITY\Anonymous Logon” | where {$_.ExtendedRights -like “ms-exch-smtp-accept-authoritative-domain-sender”} | Format-List